# really slow active directory lookup from member server when adding user permissions to folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, permissions

I have a unique issue with a current server 2008 r2 deployment that is a member server on our internal domain. When I create a folder and set the permissions from the security tab, if I choose to lookup in the active directory name list and then hit the "Find Now" radio button, it takes really long to audit and present the users and security groups.

I tried this with a couple of the domain controllers and they are really quick to present the audited users.

I have verified my dns settings and did some nslookups to verify that computer names and such are queried quickly.

To clarify this server has a static ip address using the ipv4 settings or tab from network connections. ipv6 is left checked on.

Is there anything i can check to verify if there is an issue.

Comment: is this server in the correct ad based site?

Comment: tony Roth. Yes this is in the correct site and there is only one site. Nothing fancy in organizational units either very vanilla deployment.